# Why PyTypeObject has so many specific members for specific functionality

Tags: python, c, interpreter, cpython

For example, the `PyFloat_Type` has many operations in `tp_as_number`. When this type object gets initialized, all these operations will be written into `tp_dict` of it with slots.

On the other hand, when I write a custom class with `__add__` in it, it's `tp_dict` will have `__add__`. This `__add__` function will be written into `tp_as_number` of the type object with slots when the type object gets initialized.

I think `tp_dict` has recorded all the information we need. Why do we need other members such as `tp_as_number`? Is this just a historical issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because when a C level function is using your type, it isn't performing lookup by name in `tp_dict` (slow), it's directly pulling the pointer from `tp_as_number` (fast).

A couple pointer dereferences is a trivial cost, requires no reference counting boilerplate, etc.; the cost is measured in single digit cycles most of the time, where a `dict` lookup is a couple orders of magnitude more expensive or so.

The common case is actually `tp_as_number`, [since `a + b` will actually use `tp_as_number` (or `tp_as_sequence`)](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/ce31ee3b1e69/Objects/abstract.c#l888) knowing that it is synchronized with the equivalent entries in `tp_dict`; if simple addition required a `dict` lookup, CPython would be much slower than it is.

Comment: Thank you very much. So, tp_as_number is used because of lookup speed, and tp_dict is used because sometimes we want do things such as super(MyFloat, self).__add__(other). Is that right?

Comment: @delphifirst: Yup. Or reference the `__add__` for some other purpose, e.g. to generate values that are some other value + 1 efficiently, `map((1).__add__, mynums)`.